# lcd tv stopped working (dvi to hdim)

Tags: windows-7, hardware, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup,
1: a computer monitor connected via vga
2: a samsung lcd tv conntected via dvi->hdim cable

Until yesterday, this setup was working just fine. Today when I booted windows 7, the bios & windows loading ... screen shows up fine on my lcd tv

however, when windows loads and shows my desktop, my TV goes blank, and I only get the desktop on my computer monitor.

When I go to "screen resolution" and "detect", I only see my computer monitor listed.

As far as I know, no new display drivers were installed, I am using nvadia gt300.

Also, since the bios/welcome screen does show up on my TV, I can root out the tv/cable being faulty.

has anyone encountered something similar before ?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. I de- and reinstalled drivers, I deinstalled the 11/18 Windows Update, I turned my monitor off and on again at least a dozen times as did I unplug and replug the HDMI cable - nothing worked. 
Then, in an act of despair, I unplugged my monitor's power cable, replugged it and.... here we go again!

HTH!

Chris

Comment: Thanks for the input Chris, I got mine resolved .. but wasn't sure exactly what fixed it ... what I did was 1: uninstall nvidia driver, 2: plugged the DVI cable into another port on my TV 3: reinstalled driver 4: reboot .. this seems to have fixed the issue. Although I got the issue resolved, I am still not certain what the root cause as my driver was up to date and it worked fine up till that point.